# How I can insert this date '10-JUL-88' to SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How I can insert this date '10-JUL-88' to SQL Developer?

Comment: 88, which century?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Developer edition?

Comment: did you mean 1888 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_date()` to convert your string to a `date` datatype:

```
to_date('10-JUL-88', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Note: `88` this will translate as year `2088`. If you want `1988`, then specify the 4-digit year instead:

```
to_date('10-JUL-1988', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a date constant:

```
date '1988-07-10'
```

This is the standard format for date constants, which Oracle supports.

Note:  If the string is actually in a column, then you will need `to_date()` as GMB suggests.